# How to set corner radius for all corners with image view rendered from UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext

Tags: ios, swift

This is how it looks before:

[image]

and after I generate dragging view:

[image]

and this is how I generate the dragging view from cell:

```
private func setupDraggingViewForCell(cell: BWStudentWishlistBookCollectionViewCell) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cell.bounds.size, false, 0)
    cell.bookImageView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    draggingView = UIImageView(image: UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext())
    draggingView?.clipsToBounds = true
    draggingView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    draggingView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
    draggingView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    view.addSubview(draggingView!)

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

> As you can see, only one corner is rounded. Why?

Comment: i think your dragging view is smaller then image .. and you have clips to bound = yes possibly

Comment: I think you have to set draggingView's frame (especially origins)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the clipsToBounds to false, and probably it would solve the problem in your case. Otherwise it will show you the full frame of the cover, and you can decide afterwards what to do.

```
draggingView?.clipsToBounds = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Directly add this code into your custom cell otherwise as per your need.......

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        imageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero
        imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 2

 //If you added Aspect to Fill 
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
```

I hope this will help you... (Y)

Answer (score -2):

don't know but try to round image than imageView

```
func makeRoundedImage(image: UIImage, radius: Float) -> UIImage {
    var imageLayer: CALayer = CALayer.layer
    imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)
    imageLayer.contents = (image.CGImage as! AnyObject)
    imageLayer.masksToBounds = true
    imageLayer.cornerRadius = 10
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
    imageLayer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    var roundedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return roundedImage
}
```

and then set image to you image view. and clear background color of dragableView

Hope it will help..!